# How do I set the date to the epoch of a linux (raspbian flavor) system, i.e., 1 January 1970 00:00:00?

Tags: linux, date

I am trying to set up a Raspberry Pi with the date and time to the beginning of time from the linux point of view. In my understanding, the epoch is 1 January 1970 00:00:00.

The first step was to set the timezone to UTC and then set the time to epoch.

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC
$ sudo date -s "1 January 1970 00:00:00"
```

To my surprise the `date` command returned

```
date: cannot set date: Invalid argument
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

After some brief experimentation I found that

```
$ sudo date -s "1 January 1970 02:49:00"
```

worked and

```
$ sudo date -s "1 January 1970 02:48:00"
```

returned the invalid argument error.

I have read the man pages for `date` but I haven't seen any clues. I think I am missing something fundamental here. Is there an explanation for this behavior or some piece of documentation that explains it? Does it have to do with sidereal time vs. solar time?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the `$TZ` variable set?

Answer (score 0):

After I posted my question the StackExchange system suggest this related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533393/why-cannot-i-set-the-date-of-my-gnu-linux-machines-to-the-epoch?rq=1) sp the mystery is solved.